# Csv Files & Java

Tags: java, csv

Searching through google didn't help me out.

I've got a csv file [called dataset.csv] which has many rows of information, using a "," delimeter.

The information is about businesses [name of business, type etc.]. On the very first row there are the categories:

> **[city,review_count,rating,name,full_address,type,categories/0,categories/1,
>   working_days,working hours,max_reservations]** = 11 of them.

But not a single row has all 11 of these information.

Example of 2 rows :

> *Fountain Hills, AZ 85268",business,Bars,American (New),2,9:00-17:00,15*
>
> *Gilbert,8,2,Salon Lola,"3479 E Baseline Rd*

Some information is missing, not the same though in each row. There are a few that has all of these 11 infos given.

I would like to understand somehow the way to read this csv file, and see, if its possible , where the info is empty , to put a null or something.

Thanks in advance and sorry for possible vocabulary and grammar mistakes !

Comment: if this is true, it's an invalid file.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter No, if you look at the data OP posted, they have a opening double quote, but no closing double quote... which leads me to believe their data has text qualifiers that OP has ignored, meaning OP's data contains commas that are not meant as delimiters. `Gilbert,8,2,Salon Lola,"3479 E Baseline Rd` there's probably a comma after "Rd" here, which is breaking OP's line.

Comment: Before we go on, please correct your examples. The double quotes should have come in pairs. They mean that commas within the pair of double quotes are to be ignored.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your responses everybody. The quotes in the exampes dont have a pair, i copy pasted those examples exactly as they were in the csv

Comment: A thought.  Has the CSV file lost a double quote somewhere, so from that point forward everything that was inside a double quote is now outside and *vice versa*?  I've still got the scars from when something similar happened to me once.

Comment: Inside a quoted field a newline doesn't end the record but is part of the field value. So one record can span multiple lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two rows look to be actually two pieces of a single row, if you take the following

```
Fountain Hills, AZ 85268",business,Bars,American (New),2,9:00-17:00,15

Gilbert,8,2,Salon Lola,"3479 E Baseline Rd
```

and add the bottom row to the top row you get the following

```
Gilbert,8,2,Salon Lola,"3479 E Baseline Rd Fountain Hills, AZ 85268",business,Bars,American (New),2,9:00-17:00,15

[city, review_count, rating, name, full_address, type, categories/0, categories/1, working_days, working hours, max_reservations]
```

Which lines up with the column descriptors at the beginning of the file, 11 for 11. It's weird to have the second row be the start of the first row but this would be my best guess as to why it looks like rows are missing column values.

I would bet that if you find the first occurrence of your incomplete rows the first one is the start and the second on is the other half. Instead of the example you gave us which might in fact be a second half of a previous row and the first half of the next row.